# CloudPage - Undefined JSON Value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

I'm trying to retrieve data from a json file that i published as a cloudpage

```
result = HTTP.Get("https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/xxxxx");
jsonObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Content.toString());
Write("<p>Name: " +jsonObj.countries.name);
```

i don't know why i'm getting `Name: undefined`

to remove doubts, I tried this too :

```
var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest("https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/xxxxx");
var resp = req.send();
var jsonObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content)); 
Write("<p>Name: " +jsonObj.countries.name);
```

but i'm still getting the same result

Here's my JSON File

```
    {
      "countries": [
      {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},
      {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"},
      {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"},
      {"name": "Andorra", "code": "AD"},
      {"name": "Angola", "code": "AO"},
      {"name": "Anguilla", "code": "AI"},
      {"name": "Antarctica", "code": "AQ"},
      {"name": "Antigua and Barbuda", "code": "AG"},
      {"name": "Argentina", "code": "AR"},
    ]
    }
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"countries" in your object is an array.
You want data from the first (0th) element in the array when parsing.

Also, Cloudpages return responses as gzip.

The jsonObj in your code, when printed out, is gibberish and cannot be parsed.

You need to specify an `accept-encoding` header for the HTTPGET, in the structure documented here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_httpGet.htm?search_text=http.get

This worked in my test:

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core",1);
var headerNames = ["accept-encoding"];
var headerValues = ["gzip"];
var result = HTTP.Get("https://pub.s6.exacttarget.com/yyyyyy",headerNames,headerValues);
var jsonObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Content.toString());
Write("Name: " +jsonObj.countries[0].name);
</script>
```

Comment: I did, but i'm getting the same result :') I think there's an issue with the cloudPage. because i succed to get data from different APIs, like this : [link](https://api.printful.com/countries)

Comment: is your cloudpage a code resource of type JSON?

Comment: Yes my code resource is a JSON type

Comment: There was another problem, missing accept-encoding header. I got it working and edited my answer.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you so much :D